# Combinatorics with some kind of encryption

Tags: combinatorics

so I got this complicated question:

I have a got a safe, and a group of 8 people. To every person in my group I give equal amount of keys (not necessarily the same keys tho), I want that every sub group of 5 or more people will be able to open my safe. Every sub group of 4 or less people will not be able to.

What's the minimum number of locks I need to put on my safe ?

It's possible that to have many keys to same lock of course.

Comment: Well the easiest solution would be to have $5\binom{8}{5} = 280$ locks, so that each possible $5$-combination of people is represented. I'm not sure if this is the smallest possible solution. (Also, if you're considering this for an application, may I suggest a secret sharing scheme instead?)

Comment: This isn't for an application, dont worry :) I need a way to prove that the number you suggested is indeed the minimum number of locks